# Calculate the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} (a^x+b^x-c^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Calculate the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} (a^x+b^x-c^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ where $a>b>c>0$.

First,
$$\exp\left( \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln(a^x+b^x-c^x)}{x} \right)$$

Next,
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} a^x + b^x - c^x = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} a^x \left[1 + (b/a)^x - (c/a)^x \right] = \infty$$.

Since, $\ln(\infty) = \infty$ we may use L'Hopital's rule. The expression inside the exponent is:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{a^x\ln(a)+b^x\ln(b)-c^x\ln(c)}{a^x+b^x-c^x}$$

Which again is $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. Is that the right way?

Comment: This by the way is the Power mean, which appears in a lot of places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem can be solved by Squeezing, using minimal algebraic manipulation. Note that for positive $x$ we have
$$a^x\lt a^x+b^x-c^x\lt 2a^x.$$
Now take the $x$-th roots. We get
$$a\lt (a^x+b^x-c^x)^{1/x}\lt 2^{1/x}a.$$
But $\lim_{x\to\infty} 2^{1/x}=1$, and it's over.

Comment: Great! Sometimes you just work like a robot, and doesn't notice the little tricks like Squeeze Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the correct trick but in the wrong place: Since $a > b > c$, the term $a^x$ will dominate the other two in the parenthetical expression as $x \to \infty$.

Factoring that term out gives

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left[(a^x)^{\frac{1}{x}} \left(1 + \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^x - \left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right]$.

The first factor in the brackets is just $a$, which can be factored out, leaving an easier limit to evaluate.

Comment: That should be $(a^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\dots$, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the catch Thomas, I fixed it. The OP deleted an earlier version of the problem while I was writing a solution and reversed the ordering of the constants when he reposted it, and I got a bit sloppy when rewriting it.

Comment: Thank you. The rest would be $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} a\cdot \exp\left( \frac{\ln(1+(b/a)^x - (c/a)^x}{x} \right) = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} a\cdot e^0 = a$$